# Two display providers have the same name

Tags: fedora, nvidia, gpu, nouveau

I'm following this [tutorial](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PRIME) to make my discrete GPU the primary one. 
It requires to create a `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-gpu.conf` like this:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nouveau"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "nouveau"
    Driver      "nouveau"
    BusID       "PCI:x:x:x" # Sample: "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nouveau"
    Device "nouveau"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "intel"
    Driver      "intel"
    BusID       "PCI:x:x:x"  # Sample: "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection
```

And to enable the output from LVDS1 and VGA, we need to run:
`$ xrandr --setprovideroutputsource Intel nouveau`
However, when I list all the providers in my machine:

```
$  xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x74 cap: 0xf, Source Output, Sink Output, Source Offload, Sink Offload crtcs: 3 outputs: 2 associated providers: 1 name:modesetting
Provider 1: id: 0x3f cap: 0x5, Source Output, Source Offload crtcs: 0 outputs: 0 associated providers: 1 name:modesetting
```

As you can see, both provider 1 and provider 2 have the same name `modesetting`. 
So, my question is: How can I put provider name into `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-gpu.conf` and how I run command `xrandr --setprovideroutputsource` in this situation ?

My OS is Fedora 30 and the discrete is Nvidia geforce 840M.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This may not be an option for you, but if you never use the iGPU, try disabling it in the BIOS. This way, the dGPU is the only provider available and will always be selected automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to the goal of the question - set provider output source also works with provider numbers, not only with string names:

```
xrandr --setprovideroutputsource 1 0
```

However, I haven't found how to specify provider name when using a custom X.Org configuration instead of auto-detection.